# TV mounting bracket removal

Tags: mounting, television, brackets

How do you remove this type of TV bracket? (separating the TV-mounted rails from the wall mounted bracket) For context, this bracket is likely 15+ years old. It doesn't appear to have pull tabs on the vertical bars. We've tried lifting the tv and tilting, but it doesn't work. The locking mechanism seems to have something to do with the flat bar that runs horizontally with the two large holes in it closest to the camera, however we haven't been able to figure out how to get that to move as well. [image]

**[Resolved]**
There were two bars that had to be pulled out to the side and up. It required prying with hand-tools to get it to move. Another issue with this setup is the TV was mounted inside/flush to wall, making it more difficult.
(see below picture with TV removed)

[image]

Comment: Judging by the locking holes, the frontward plate on which the lower hooks are secured will swivel out and up.

Comment: You should remove the "Resolved" part added to the original question and place it as an actual answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's anything like the one I have lying around, the bar just pulls straight out (parallel to the wall and away from the center of the television).
[image]

(Via https://www.sanus.com/assets/products/vmpl2/documents/VMPL2_manual.pdf)

Comment: Yup. the holes in the locking bar are literally so you can put a padlock on it. From what I recall of the similar ones I've used, pull the bar out, then the TV should be free to lift up/away.

Comment: Thanks. The mount in my question ended-up having two bars that had to be pulled up/out on both ends. Required prying with a footlong screwdriver to get it loose, as the bar had angled grooves with close tolerances and not a simple sliding bar.